# How to sort meteorological data for different time scales

Tags: r, sorting, weather

I have a time series of monthly precipitation as a data frame including date and precipitation.

> date <- (JAN-2001, FEB-2001, MAR-2001, ....., DEC-2010)
> precipitation <- (0, 3.3, 8.8, ....., 304.5)

mydata1 <- data.frame(date, precipitation)

---

I want to calculate accumulated precipitation for each season in each year.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I "reproduced" your data to give out the solution.

```r
#install.packages("hydroTSM")
#install.packages("lubridate")
library(dplyr)


#Reproduce the data
date <- paste0(toupper(month.abb), "-", rep(2001:2010, each=12))
precipitation  <- rnorm(n = length(date), mean = 10, sd = 1)

# Convert the date column into a Date format
date <- lubridate::my(date)
year <- lubridate::year(date)

# Cut the date by season 
season <- hydroTSM::time2season(date, out.fmt = "seasons")

# Make a dataframe
df <- tibble(year, date, season, precipitation)

# Group the data by year and season 
accumulated_precipitation <- 
  df %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  group_by(year, season) %>% 
  summarise(total_precipitation = sum(precipitation))


accumulated_precipitation 
#> # A tibble: 40 x 3
#> # Groups:   year [10]
#>     year season total_precipitation
#>    <dbl> <chr>                <dbl>
#>  1  2001 autumm                29.3
#>  2  2001 spring                30.0
#>  3  2001 summer                29.7
#>  4  2001 winter                30.5
#>  5  2002 autumm                31.4
#>  6  2002 spring                30.5
#>  7  2002 summer                28.5
#>  8  2002 winter                28.0
#>  9  2003 autumm                30.5
#> 10  2003 spring                30.4
#> # ... with 30 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @Sorena, please accept the answer if that worked, else let me know